# Range in MYSQL not working

Tags: php, time, mariadb

I would like to achieve the following query. It selects the rows with the due date (entries.end < 1 hour)

```
SET SESSION time_zone = '+8:00';
SELECT chatID, description
FROM entries
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF( 
SECOND , entries.end, NOW( ) ) BETWEEN 0 AND 3601
```

However, in reality, it is not working. Not even the below query

```
SET SESSION time_zone = '+8:00';
SELECT chatID, description
FROM entries
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF( 
SECOND , entries.end, NOW( ) )<=3600
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF( 
SECOND , entries.end, NOW( ) )>=0
```

Nevertheless, the following code is working.

```
SET SESSION time_zone = '+8:00';
SELECT chatID, description
FROM entries
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF( 
SECOND , entries.end, NOW( ) ) <=3600
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you everyone here.

**Edit**
[image: Table structure]
[image: Query]

Comment: What datatype is `entries.end`

Comment: @RiggsFolly It is DATETIME

Comment: What happens if you increase the range `TIMESTAMPDIFF( SECOND , entries.end, NOW() ) BETWEEN 0 AND 3333601`

Comment: @RiggsFolly unfortunately, no rows are selected

Comment: Maybe it would help if we could at least see an example ot the column `end` that you expect to be selected by this query

Comment: Also what version of MYSQL are you using? I am not sure why I am asking this but it might be relevant

Comment: 10.0.19-MariaDB is the version i use. Photos are added above. Thank you a lot!

Comment: That looks like your query is actually returning a result??!!??

Comment: Your screenshot contains result, but you said that query returns nothing. Why do you think so?

Comment: From my question, there are 3 queries, only the last one returns result. I have no idea

Comment: The BETWEEN style works for me. Is the timezone causing you issues

Comment: Are you sure `end` column is DATETIME? See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2b84/1) and [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c1222/1).

Comment: @wchiquito i think i got the gist of my error. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Don't hide your column inside a function.

```
WHERE entries.end >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
  AND entries.end <= NOW()
```

is easy to write and clear.  Furthermore, if `end` is indexed, there is a chance that the index will be used for better efficiency.